# Check Dataframes with Python

Tags: python, pandas

I got multiple excel file which needs to be need if OLD data is matching NEW data. Normally I use dataframe.equals but since the NEW data is containing additional columns this doesn't work anymore.

Very excel file contains two tabs with OLD and NEW data. I have to check if the OLD data is matching per record in NEW. The issue of NEW is that columns aren't in the same order, additional columns plus record aren't in the same order.

[Table OLD and Table NEW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bZLS.png)

The code I normally use to check but it is giving

```
import os
import pandas as pd

TargetFolder = os.listdir('Dir')

for file in TargetFolder:

    df = pd.ExcelFile('TargetFolder' + file)

    dfPrep = pd.read_excel(df, 'OLD')
    dfCE = pd.read_excel(df, 'NEW')

    Checkdf = dfPrep.equals(dfCE)
```

Comment: I don't see a question here, but maybe you should make a list of columns and explicitly check them one at a time in a loop?

Comment: I don't see which records aren't matching from table OLD in table NEW

Comment: @TomH, in the given example, you need to compare only the first six records/rows ?

Comment: @abokey the entire dataframe

Comment: Maybe create a list of the new columns and drop them from the df. Then you can sort the df on one of the columns to try and more accurately align them? Just a though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can use [**`pandas.DataFrame.loc`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to select/pick the exact `OLD` columns from the `NEW` ones then use [**`pandas.DataFrame.sort_values`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) to reorder the rows by the two columns `Column4` and `Column8`.

Try this :

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

a_directory= "path_to_the_folder_containing_the_excel_files"

for file in Path(a_directory).glob("*.xlsx"):
    dfPrep = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name="OLD")
    dfCE = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name="NEW")

    dfCE_adapted= (
                    dfCE.loc[:, dfPrep.columns]
                        .sort_values(by=["Column4", "Column8"], ignore_index=True)
                   )

    Checkdf= dfPrep.equals(dfCE_adapted)
    
    if Checkdf:
        print(file.stem)
    else:
        pass
```

If the two sheets `OLD` and `NEW` matches, then the Excel filename will be printed.

Comment: really appreciate it @abokey. I still have an issue because rows aren't with the same sorting. Is there a way to sort the dataframe on different columns?

Comment: Yes, you can use `pandas.DataFrame.sort_values`. I updated my answer with a sort on two columns. You can put as much as you want and also specifiy the type of the sort (for each column) by using the boolean parameter `ascending`. Read more here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html

Comment: In your case, we need to use an ascending sort on both columns `Column4` (A, B, C, ..) and `Column8` (1, 2).

Comment: thanks @abokey but the sorting is working only I'm still receiving a false. Printed some output a the tables https://ibb.co/W264nCr

Comment: That's because the index needs to be reset after the sort or has to be ignored when sorting. I updated my answer ;)

Comment: thanks @abokey, seems everything is solved. thanks for your support